# How to use parameterized IN with RPostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I have the following query:

```
query <- 'SELECT field1, field2
from mytable
where field1 IN $1
AND field2 <= $2
ORDER BY field1 ASC, field2 DESC;'

params <- list(list('A','B'), as.character(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), tz="UTC")))

print(params)
```

I run:

```
df <- dbGetQuery(conn, query, params=params)
```

And I get:

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
LINE 7: WHERE field1 IN ($1)
                                             ^
)
```

How can I use a /parameterized/ query with an `IN` in a `WHERE` clause in RPostgreSQL?

Comment: You misunderstand the API. We just send strings so I fear you need to interpolate _before_ it hits the wire.  Unless I keep forgetting some magic that was added later.

Comment: Darn, as happens whenever I write R: I was banking on the present existence of some @DirkEddelbuettel magic.